# Terrence Tao Measure Theory, hash symbol

Tags: measure-theory, notation

This is the first time I encounter this hash symbol. What is it supposed to mean?

[image: t]

Comment: It stands for "Number of elements" or equivalently "Cardinality"

Comment: $\#A$ is the number of elements (possibly $\infty$) in the set $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [online version](http://www.faculty.jacobs-university.de/poswald/teaching/RealAnal2/handouts/TaoMeasureTheory.pdf), the explanation is in the next page.

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the $\#$ is commonly used in number theory as an operator that returns the cardinality of the set, or the *number* of elements in the set (hence the use of the "number sign").